# Auto detect otp for chrome 84 and above using WebOtp api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this exception "DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled." in WebOtp api.

Below is my code

```
if(Number(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./)[2])>= 84){
  console.log('if 84 or above')
if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
 console.log('1')
    const ac = new AbortController();
 
    navigator.credentials.get({
      otp: { transport:['sms'] },
      signal: ac.signal
    }).then(otp => {
       console.log('2', otp.code)
       // ac.abort();
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log('3')
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

It is not waiting for the otp sms to popup, and directly go to the catch loop and throw this error "DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled."

Comment: You run this from an https:// or localhost origin? You never abort the AbortControl? You call this from an user-gesture? You are not in a frame?

Comment: @Kaiido  Yes i run this from localhost. I uncommented the "ac.abort" line and tried but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I didn't mean to uncomment that line, I was asking if somehow something else could be calling this method. What about the two other questions (user-gesture + iframe)? Does the example at https://web-otp.glitch.me/ works for you?

Comment: Yes. I tried that. it works for.